# Bash script not echoing after executing jar file

Tags: bash

I recently made a bash script which automatically creates a Minecraft server using the server.jar file. I told it to echo a string which is a command in Minecraft after a certain delay, in order to have it be echoed after the server is done loading. For some reason, after finishing loading the Minecraft world, it just doesn't echo that string.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir minecraft_server

cd minecraft_server

wget https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/e00c4052dac1d59a1188b2aa9d5a87113aaf1122/server.jar

java -Xmx5G -Xms3G -jar server.jar nogui

sed -i "s/^eula.*/eula=true/" /home/my name/minecraft_server/eula.txt

sed -i "s/^server-port.*/server-port=40004/" /home/my name/minecraft_server/server.properties

java -Xmx5G -Xms3G -jar server.jar nogui

sleep 60

echo "/op My Username"
```

Comment: Does the command `java -Xmx5G -Xms3G -jar server.jar nogui` run the server in the background, or the foreground (or is that not what runs the server at all)? If it runs in the foreground, the commands following it will not be executed until after it exits. Also, are you expecting it to echo the string to the minecraft server, or to the terminal you ran the script from?

Comment: 1. Yes, the command runs the server
2. I expect it to echo it to the terminal i ran it from, but that also acts as the command prompt for the minecraft server since I ran it with "nogui"

Comment: Sending output to the terminal does not cause it to be reflected back as input. That `echo` command will (when/if it executes) print "/op My Username" on the screen, but it will not be passed to the minecraft server (or anything else) as input.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ready-made minecraft server launch script, which also feature `screen` for remote management. Although if you want to go a bit further by yourself, here is a cleaned-up version of your script. It works but does not include the `op` command. This need to be dealt with separately.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

server_dl_url='https://launcher.mojang.com/v1/objects/e00c4052dac1d59a1188b2aa9d5a87113aaf1122/server.jar'
server_dir='./minecraft_server'
server_jar='server.jar'

if mkdir -p "${server_dir}" && cd "${server_dir}"; then

  # If server.jar does not exist, download it
  if ! [ -e "${server_jar}" ]; then
    if ! wget --output-document="${server_jar}" "${server_dl_url}"; then
      printf "Could not dowload %s from %s\\n" \
        "${server_jar}" "${server_dl_url}"
        exit 1
    fi >&2
  fi

  # Check if it has eula.txt, if not, generate it with --initSettings
  if ! [ -e 'eula.txt' ]; then
    # Initializes 'server.properties' and 'eula.txt', then quits
    if ! java -jar "${server_jar}" --initSettings --nogui; then
      printf "Could not initialize 'server.properties' and 'eula.txt'\\n"
      exit 1
    fi >&2
  fi
  if ! grep -q '^eula=true' 'eula.txt'; then
    sed -i.bak 's/^eula=.*/eula=true/' 'eula.txt'
  fi

  # Run the actual server
  java -Xmx5G -Xms3G -jar server.jar nogui &
fi
```